# xcode ios - updating scheduled timer whenever slider is adjusted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer

So I have a slider and a `startTimer` button that calls a `nextFood()` function via a `Timer.scheduledTimer` interval based on the slider's value.

What I'm trying to do is even after I pressed the startTimer button, if I move the slider to a different value, the scheduledTimer should adjust to the new value and call the nextFood function according to the new interval without trying to press the startTimer button again.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet var sliderVal: UISlider!
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    delayLabel.text = "Delay: " + String(Int(sender.value)) + "s"
}

//start timer according to slider val
var timer = Timer()
@IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //print(Int(sliderVal.value))
    startButton.isEnabled = false

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Double(Int(sliderVal.value)), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.nextFood), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

So far my code only works for the value the slider is set when the startTimer button is pressed initially but doesn't adjust when I move the slider. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can't change the time interval of the timer once it has started.

What you can do is this: Upon slider action, invalidate the previous timer, create a new timer, and fire it with the new interval.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728011/swift-nstimer-dynamically-changing-interval) is also related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create two `@IBAction`s. You can create one common `@IBAction` and connect the button and slider action to that.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    var timer: Timer?

    @IBAction func updateTimer(_ sender: Any) {

        label.text = "Delay: " + String(Int(slider.value)) + "s"
        startButton.isEnabled = false
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Double(Int(slider.value)), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.nextFood), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }
    @objc func nextFood() {
        ///
    }
}
```

**Note:** Before initialising new `Timer` instance, invalidate the previous instance. Else multiple timer instances will be calling the `nextFood` method

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `DispatchSourceTimer` which can be restarted without recreating the timer instance

```
var timer : DispatchSourceTimer?

@IBOutlet var sliderVal: UISlider!
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let delay = Int(sender.value)
        delayLabel.text = "Delay: \(delay) s"
        startTimer(with: delay)
    }

//start timer according to slider val
@IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //print(Int(sliderVal.value))
    startButton.isEnabled = false
    startTimer(with: Int(sliderVal!.value))
}

func startTimer(with delay: Int) {
    let interval : DispatchTime = .now() + .seconds(delay)
    if timer == nil {
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
        timer!.schedule(deadline:interval, repeating: TimeInterval(delay))
        timer!.setEventHandler {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nextFood()
            }
        }
        timer!.resume()
    } else {
        timer!.schedule(deadline:interval, repeating: TimeInterval(delay))
    }
}
```